# Apply style to parent based on property on child, with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

How do I apply a style to the parent of an element if it has a specific property? Here's the example I'm working with...

```
<div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="inner active"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

...I want to apply a background color to the out div when its child element with an 'inner' class also contains the 'active' class. Here's the jQuery solution I hacked together, which doesn't seem to be working...

```
if ($("div.inner").hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).parent().css("background", "yellow");
};
```

Does anyone have a fix, or better approach, in mind? Thanks.

Also, optionally, how do I get it to apply the style based on specific text within the 'inner' div as opposed to a specific class being applied to it? Thanks again.

Comment: There are a few good solutions offered below.. I'd only add that you may consider using a class instead of inline styles `$("div.inner.active").parent().addClass('activeparent');` so that you can easily change them without having to modify javascript.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$("div.inner.active").parent().css("background", "yellow");
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g4gBx/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is important also to note that as of right now there is no way to affect the styles of a parent element based on its child elements attributes, properties or text in pure CSS.

Comment: The asker is asking about jQuery not CSS, in jQuery there are multiple ways to do what is being asked, some of which are in other answers already posted.

Answer (score 0):

$(".active").parents('div').css("text-align", "center");

Comment: Kindly explain your code. Don't write code directly without explaining anything.