# CSS selector to check an attribute of a child div and style based on the result?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there some kind of CSS selector method I can use to get an attribute of a child element, and style the parent based on that element's value?

For example;

```
<div class="bigparent">
    <div class="message">
        <div class="iconcontainer">
            <div class="iconitself" label="thisone"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="textcontainer">
            <div class="text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="message">
        <div class="iconcontainer">
            <div class="iconitself" label="thatone"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="textcontainer">
            <div class="text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Say I need to get the first .message .iconcontainer .iconitself label, and edit the CSS of its .message parent. Is this possible in CSS, or would I have to resort to JS?

If it's even possible. Thanks in advance, guys~

P.S; I can't change the HTML any, as I'm simply writing a CSS theme. Also, I only need it for FireFox, so no cross-browser worries there.

Comment: There is no combinator that allows backtracking up the DOM, so the second requirement isn't possible.

Comment: No, you cannot `ascend` the DOM with CSS, only `descend`.

Comment: There's no sort of "this element has this element which has a 'label' which is 'this'" sort of thing?

Comment: Could you attach a js file? You could achieve that with jQuery.

Comment: Possible jQuery solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10692538/2470724

Comment: As other's noted, no. However, if you are more specific about what "styling" you want changed, there _may_ be a workaround for it (too little info to know for sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot.. yet. The [CSS4 Selectors Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) shows a way to choose the subject of a rule, but it is not implemented in any browsers. To note, hopefully you will be able to do this soon (from the spec)

> For example, the following selector represents a list item LI unique child of an ordered list OL:
>
> `OL > LI:only-child`
>
> However the following one represents an ordered list OL having a unique child, that child being a LI:
>
> `!OL > LI:only-child`

Comment: I wish people would stop citing unstable drafts until it's decided whether or not this sort of feature will actually be usable in CSS, especially when the Selectors 4 draft has begun hinting at the contrary. I don't mean to target you or make you feel bad, but given recent changes, this sort of thing on SO is just getting frustrating to see time and again, and I feel the need to make a statement about it, at least for future readers.

Comment: @BoltClock Sure, I'm glad you did. Nevertheless, I'm very excited for this particular decision and wanted others who may have the same question to know that it _may_ be coming, in one form or another. I think "No, but hopefully soon" is a better answer than just "No," right?